# FlatList update is slow

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a FlatList that holds 5000 items. There is an option to switch on the "Select Mode", which renders a checkbox next to each item. Whenever I press the corresponding button to switch to that mode, there is a noticeable delay before checkboxes are actually rendered.

This is my state:

```
{
  list: data, // data is taken from an external file
  selectedItems: [] // holds ids of the selected items,
  isSelectMode: false
}
```

My list:

```
<FlatList
  data={list}
  extraData={this.state}
  keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
  renderItem={this.renderItem}
  removeClippedSubviews
/>
```

My list item:

```
<ListItem
  title={item.title}
  isCheckboxVisible={isSelectMode}
  isChecked={isChecked}
  onPress={() => this.toggleItem(item)}
/>
```

Each list item implements `shouldComponentUpdate`:

```
...

shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
  const { isCheckboxVisible, isChecked } = this.props;
  return isChecked !== nextProps.isChecked || isCheckboxVisible !== nextProps.isCheckboxVisible;
}

...
```

I always thought that FlatList only renders items that a currently visible within the viewport, but here it feels like the entire list of 5000 items is re-rendered. Is there anything I can improve here? Or perhaps I am doing something totally wrong?

Full code: https://snack.expo.io/@pavermakov/a-perfect-flatlist

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I have same structure like checkbox to each item but every time I click one of them its changes slowly.

Comment: Unfortunately no, still struggling.